# How to connect SerpApi to Pycharm? I've set the venv on the terminal

Tags: pycharm, serpapi

I've set the venv on the terminal,
but when I "import os" and then from crewai (it does not work).

I need help to set crewai and connect to Ai Api, please.

Note: I'm starting with code.

I hope to get a solution to my problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.